# Mean first passage time and Kramer's problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

I've a HW problem and I've no idea how to proceed. Could someone can provide any hints?

Consider a particle trapped in a potential $V(x)$ with infinite boundary condition, in between these reflecting barriers exist finite barriers the particle can cross. The mean first-passage time is the average time a particle needs to cross a barrier and reach $x_{B}$ for the first time when starting at position $x_{0} < x_{B}$. The formula for the mean-passage time is
$$
\tau_{MPT} = \frac{1}{D} \int_{x_{0}}^{x_B} dx^{'} e^{\beta V(x^{'})} \int_{x_{L}}^{x^{'}} dx^{''} e^{- \beta V (x^{''})},
$$
with $x_{L} < x_{0}$ denoting the position of the reflective barrier and $D = 1 / (\gamma \beta)$ as the diffusion constant.

a.) Consider the system with one barrier in the middle region
$$
\begin{equation}
V(x) =
\begin{cases}
\infty, & x \leq x_{L} \; \text{and} x \geq x_{B} \\
V_{A}, & x_{L} < x < x_{0} \\
0, & x_{0} \leq x < x_{B}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
sketch the potential and compute the mean first-passage time to reach $x_{B}$ starting at $x_{0}$. Discuss the limits $V_{A} \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

b.) Derive Kramer's formula for the barrier-crossing rate $\kappa$
$$
\begin{equation}
 \kappa = \frac{\sqrt{V_{1}^{''} V_{2}^{''}}}{\pi \gamma} e^{- \beta (V(x_{2}) - V(x_1))}
\end{equation}
$$
rom the formula for the mean first-passage time $\tau_{MPT}$ using a saddle point approximation. Here, $V_{1,2}^{''}$ is the second derivative of the potential with respect to $x$ at $x_{1,2}$

$Hint$: A saddle point approximation is a harmonic approximation at extermal points $x_{1}$,$x_{2}$, of the potential $V(x)$ in the exponent.

Comment: You may refer to the pdf from the following link: http://physics.gu.se/~frtbm/joomla/media/mydocs/LennartSjogren/kap8.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to help you in the first part doing the integral.

$$
\tau_{MPT} = \frac{1}{D} \int_{x_{0}}^{x_B} dx^{'} e^{\beta V(x^{'})} \int_{x_{L}}^{x^{'}} dx^{''} e^{- \beta V (x^{''})}
$$
Divid the second integral into $ x_L - x_0 $ where $V=V_A$; and $ x_0 - x'$ where $V=0$.
$$
=\frac{1}{D} \int_{x_{0}}^{x_B} dx^{'} e^{\beta 0} \{ \int_{x_{L}}^{x_{0}} dx^{''} e^{- \beta V_A} + \int_{x_{0}}^{x'} dx^{''} e^{- \beta 0} \}
$$
$$
 = \frac{1}{D} \int_{x_{0}}^{x_B} dx^{'} \{  (x_{0}-x_{L}) e^{- \beta V_A} + ( x'-x_{0} )  \}
$$
$$
 = \frac{1}{D} \{ ( x_{B}-x_{0} ) (x_{0}-x_{L}) e^{- \beta V_A} +  \frac{1}{2} (x_B - x_0 )^2\}
$$
Thus,
$$
\tau_{MPT} = = \frac{1}{D} \{ ( x_{B}-x_{0} ) (x_{0}-x_{L}) e^{- \beta V_A} +  \frac{1}{2} (x_B - x_0 )^2\}
$$
[image]

Diffusion barrier locates at $x_0$ with barrier height $V_A$.